# SQL Ignoring WHERE clause

Tags: sql

M SSMS SQL
This line in my WHERE clause is throwing off the rest of my WHERE clause

```
WHERE ...
AND b.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL OR c.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL
```

For some reason when this line is commented, the query runs properly, and when it is uncommented, it ignores my entire WHERE clause.

Have I written something incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want parentheses:

```
WHERE ... AND
      (b.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL OR c.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: If it's solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.  Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)